# Retreiving the value causing a DUPLICATE_VALUE DML Exception

Tags: apex, exception, dml, dmlexception, duplicate-management

I have an inventory management system I am working on and I have the need to let users input values to be created into inventory. These values consist of numbers that are used as the name for the inventory object. I have a workflow that takes the name and populates it into a unique field to assure that no duplicates can enter the system. This works as it should.

When they are entering the numbers into the fields I am batching these numbers together so that they can create multiple inventory items in one pass. My issue is that I have been unable to find a way to get the Value of the field that is causing the DUPLICATE_VALUE. I see that I can get the field name but I would like to be able to show them exactly which Inventory Number is the one that caused the issue so they can go in an correct that specific one. I also realize that I can get the ID of the object that caused the error but this is an insert of new objects so I would not be able to query for the information after the DML failed.

Does anyone know of a way to get the value of the field that failed a uniqeness check upon insert of an object?

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Was asked to clarify a little bit.

When inserting a set of SObjects - I am wanting a DML Exception to be thrown when a duplicate value is found. This is working correctly. I need to be able to show the Value of the field that caused the duplicate check to fail. For example:

```
try{
        insert accounts;
        /// Am inserting over 3000 accounts in this scenario
    }
    catch(DmlException de){
        system.debug(de.getMessage());
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,
                                           'A Duplicate Value was found.'+
                                            'That value is: '
                // I NEED A WAY TO GET THE VALUE THAT CAUSED THE ERROR HERE);
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
    }
```

To elaborate further - If I am inserting 5 accounts and the accounts object has a unique field of "Account_Number__c". If one of these accounts I am inserting fails because the value of "Account_Number__c" was "123" and "123" already exists as a value for "Account_Number__c" on another Account record - I would like to get the value of "123" out of the DML Exception so I can return it to the user.

Edit 2: I tried the solution put out by one of the commenters and I was unable to get the Id of the record that has the value already. making a call to getDMLId(0) returns the Id of the record that failed to insert - which is null. I can parse the getMessage() response as I see that the ID is inside of this message but I would rather have a more stable way of getting this ID if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Can u please explain it in bit more clear manner . We are unable to get what is your problem itself.

Comment: If you know the account that is being inserted and the field that caused the duplicate value error then why don't you just query the accounts to find the account with the matching value?

Comment: @BarCotter - Doh - I just realized what you are saying. Good Idea. :) will try it.

Comment: @BarCotter see my update for Edit 2.

Comment: If the account didn't insert then there will be no Id on the record. Did you try use `getDmlIndex` instead?

Comment: That worked - if you want to add this to the solution I will accept it. Otherwise I can put it in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BarCotter for pointing out the getDMLIndex method on the DML Exception class. This allowed me to use my insert list to pull out the exact SObject that was causing my error and gave me all of its fields and values to display to the user. Thanks again!